# Display Records without passing parameter values or by passing Single or multiple values in parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Within my SSRS report I am passing three parameters
The Third parameter (which is a Search parameter) allows null value as well as multiple values. Reports giving results by passing null values or by passing one value to the third parameter, but throwing error when we pass more than 1 value in the third parameter.

I am using query below in the dataset to handle this case

```
IF (@Parameter3 = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM   [MyTableName] WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE  col1 IN (@Parameter1)
           AND col2 IN (@Parameter2)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM   [MyTableName] WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE  col1 IN (@Parameter1)
           AND col2 IN (@Parameter2)
           AND col3 IN (@Parameter3) 
END
```

Here Parameter 3 is used to pass null as well as multiple Values.

Comment: However I get results when I pass **single** value in @ Parameter3 and also when I pass ` NULL` Value but I am getting  **Report Error** when I Pass **Multiple** values in @Parameter 3

Answer (score 1):

`@Parameter3` should have some separation - Either using comma or any special character.

For example: If you have passed multiple values thru @Parameter3 and that separates data with comma **`,`** then your query should looks like below.

```
IF (@Parameter3 = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM   [MyTableName] WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE  col1 IN (@Parameter1)
           AND col2 IN (@Parameter2)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM   [MyTableName] WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE  col1 IN (@Parameter1)
           AND col2 IN (@Parameter2)
           AND col3 IN ISNULL(@Parameter3,'NULL')
END
```

Comment: This is giving results when passing Null Value in parameter 3, but when passing  single value or mutilple values in parameter 3, Report is throwing error.

Comment: And that my above query is giving result when i am passing single value to @Parameter3 but when I pass multiple values it is throwing error.